# Hints for a complex limit: Prove if $\lim_{z \to \infty} f(z)/z = 0$ then $f(z)$ is constant.

Tags: complex-analysis

(To clarify, I would just like a *hint*. Please do not give me the answer to this problem. )
The solution to the following problem has really evaded me here:

**Problem:**
Assume that $f$ is entire and that $\lim_{z \to \infty} f(z)/z  = 0.$ Prove that $f(z)$ is constant.

**My Thoughts and Work So Far:** We know that proving that $f'(z) =  0$ or that for some fixed $c \in \mathbb{C}$, $f(z) = c$ for all $z\in \mathbb{C}$. My first approach was to use Liouville's Theorem; If I could could show that $f$ is bounded then I am done. Since $\lim_{z \to \infty} f(z)/z  = 0$, for all $\varepsilon > 0$ there exists a $N \in \mathbb{C}$ so large that if $z \geq N$ then $|f(z)/z| \leq \varepsilon$. Thus, if $C_R$ is the circle of radius $R$ centered at the point $z$, then, *as long as z is large enough* by Cauchy's Inequality
$$
|f'(z)| \leq \frac{1}{2\pi i} \oint_{C_R} \frac{f(\zeta)}{(\zeta - z)^2}\ d\zeta \leq \bigg | \frac{1}{2\pi i} \bigg | \oint_{C_R} \bigg | \frac{f(\zeta)}{(\zeta - z)^2} \bigg | d \zeta \leq \frac{1}{2\pi}  \frac{|\zeta|\varepsilon 2\pi R}{R^2} = \frac{|\zeta|\varepsilon}{R}. 
$$

Now taking the limit as $R \to \infty$ (which to me says, "let our circle around our point z dilate to an infinite radius so that it covers all of $\mathbb{C}$) 
$$|f'(z)| \leq \lim_{R \to \infty} \frac{|\zeta|\varepsilon}{R} = 0.$$

Thus $f'(z) = 0$ and $z$ was arbitrary, so $f$ must be constant.

**Why I Think Im Wrong**: I say $z$ was arbitrary, but really it is "any $z \geq N$" which really isn't all that arbitrary.

This is where I am stuck. Am I right, wrong, close, or totally lost? Any hints would be great.

**Edit:** I am very sorry but I accidentally posted this before I was done typing the problem.

Comment: You take a circle $C_R$ centered at $0$. Then you use that to estimate $\lvert f'(z)\rvert$ for arbitrary $\lvert z\rvert \leqslant R/2$ (or $\lvert z\rvert \leqslant 1$, by the identity theorem, that's enough). You get an estimate $\lvert f'(z)\rvert \leqslant K\cdot \sup \left\{\left\lvert \frac{f(\zeta)}{\zeta}\right\rvert : \lvert \zeta\rvert \geqslant R\right\}$.

Comment: What is $K$ in that last inequality?

Comment: Some constant. If you constrain $\lvert z\rvert \leqslant R/2$, then $K = 4$. More generally, for $\lvert z\rvert \leqslant R/c$, you have $K = \left(\frac{c}{c-1}\right)^2$ (or anything larger). It must be a bound for $\left(\frac{R}{R - \lvert z\rvert}\right)^2$, if you don't allow your $z$ to come too close to the circle, there is such a constant.

Comment: Of course we could be lazy and say that $\dfrac{f(z)}{z}$ has a removable singularity in $\infty$, and the value is $0$, hence $f(z)$ is holomorphic in $\infty$, thus it is a holomorphic mapping $\widehat{\mathbb{C}} \to \mathbb{C}$, hence constant (since the image is compact, hence not open).

Comment: Well we haven't covered what holomorphic is, so I don't think that I would be allowed to do that.

Comment: Since you know for some $N \in \mathbb{N}$ that $|z| > N$ gives $|f(z)| \le N$, then you just need that $f(z)$ is bounded in $\Omega = \{z \in \mathbb{C} \mid |z| \le N\}$.  Isn't that given by the fact that we can contain $\Omega$ in a compact region of $\mathbb{C}$, and since $f$ is continuous, we then have $f(\Omega)$ compact, hence bounded?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**Hint**: Use the Cauchy Integral Formula for the second derivative and show that $f'' \equiv 0$. So $f$ is a polynomial of degree at most **__**, and ....

Comment: If $f$ was a polynomial function then of degree $\geq 1$ then wouldn't $z$ simply divide out an one woulde be left with a limit that is constant or tending to infinity?

Comment: @Eric $f$ is a polynomial of degree at most $1$.

Comment: If thats true, then how could $f$ be constant? Wouldn't $f(z) = Az + B$  for some constants A,B?

Comment: @Eric If it's degree $1$, write $f(z) = az + b$. Then away from $0$, $f(z) / z = a + b/z$ tends to what as $z \to \infty$?

Comment: then $f(z)/z$ would then tend to $a$. Which seems to be a contradiction given $\lim_{z \to \infty} f(z)/z =0$.

Comment: @Eric It's not really a contradiction, it just implies that $a = 0$. So $f(z) = b$ is constant.

Answer (score 7):

**Hint:** Consider the Taylor expansion of $f$ and the Cauchy integral formula. How can you combine the two to make the desired conclusion?